# How to add yaxis grid lines beyond yaxis in HighChart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, highcharts

[X-axis labels]

Attaching Image for reference of how I want it to be-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ1L6.png

Comment: Hi, yAxis gridlines are added by default. Could you please clarify which yAxis lines would you like to add? Do you mean yAxis line as in the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tkpgnLxa/ ?

Comment: Do you mean Threshold & negative?: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-negative-color/